# Accidentally overwrote `pod` command in Terminal

Tags: ios, bash, terminal, cocoapods, ghc

I accidentally overwrote the `pod` command in my *bash* by following this [tutorial in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/extended-example-web-client-programming.html) and now I can't use *Cocoapods* any more. The tutorial showed how to build a cmd line podcast client and I installed it system-wide without thinking about the nameclash using the Haskell environment and the command `runghc Setup.hs install`. Does anyone know how I can restore the command (maybe just delete the new `pod` command that was installed)?

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrote"? If you have removed the binary then it will need to be reinstalled, but the rest of your question sounds more like maybe you wrecked your `PATH` (restore from backup?) or put in something useless like `alias pod=nothing` (in which case revert the addition). Please [edit] your question to describe in more detail what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, just remove the newly installed app ;) and if that doesn't help because you physically replaced the pod command, reinstall cocoa pods

in terminal type:

```
sudo mv `which pod` /pod_backup
```

that will not delete it but move to the home dir so you can move it back

Comment: thanks for your answer! how would I go for "removing" the newly installed app? I don't know where the new `pod` command got installed when I ran `runghc Setup.hs install`. I just uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods but that doesn't work.

Comment: edited that .. just move the executable out of the way.